# How to use the token list variable from \prop_get

Tags: expl3, token-lists, l3prop, property-list

Here is a MWE. 
I use a token list, and I can get 10 and October in the final pdf file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_my_tl
\prop_new:N \l_my_prop

\NewDocumentCommand{\myset}{m}
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { #1 }
    \prop_put:Nnn \l_my_prop {test} {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myget}{}
{
     \tl_use:N \l_my_tl
%%% comment out the above line and uncomment the below lines
%     \prop_get:NnN \l_my_prop {test} \l_tmpa_tl
%     \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\MonthName[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\or
  January \or Feburary \or March
  \or April \or May \or June
  \or July \or August \or September
  \or October \or November \or December
  \else#1\fi
}
\myset{10}
\begin{document}
\myget\\
\MonthName{\myget}
\end{document}
```

Then if I switch to prop list (as the comment says), that is,

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\myget}{}
{
     \prop_get:NnN \l_my_prop {test} \l_tmpa_tl
     \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}
```

an error is reported for `\MonthName{\myget}`

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
```

`\prop_get` recovers the value stored with key `test` from the property list `\l_my_prop`, and places this in the token list variable `\l_tmpa_tl`. And I use this variable.
Compared to the first case, I think it has something to do the `\prop_get`. But I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\prop_get:NnN` isn't expandable, so you can't use directly in `\ifcase`. When `\ifcase` tries to expand `\myget` (which isn't expandable because of `\prop_get:NnN`) it fails and TeX says `Missing number, treated as zero`.

However, the assignment you are doing to `\l_tmpa_tl` is basically useless, so you can skip that step and use `\prop_item:Nn` directly, which is expandable, and make `\myget` expandable with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_my_tl
\prop_new:N \l_my_prop

\NewDocumentCommand{\myset}{m}
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { #1 }
    \prop_put:Nnn \l_my_prop {test} {#1}
}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myget}{}
{
     % \tl_use:N \l_my_tl
%%% comment out the above line and uncomment the below lines
    \prop_item:Nn \l_my_prop {test}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\MonthName[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\or
  January \or Feburary \or March
  \or April \or May \or June
  \or July \or August \or September
  \or October \or November \or December
  \else#1\fi
}
\myset{10}
\begin{document}
\myget\\
\MonthName{\myget}
\end{document}
```

You can use the more `expl3`-*y* `\int_case:nn` as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_my_tl
\prop_new:N \l_my_prop

\NewDocumentCommand{\myset}{m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { #1 }
    \prop_put:Nnn \l_my_prop {test} {#1}
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myget}{}
  {
    \prop_item:Nn \l_my_prop {test}
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\MonthName}{m}
  {
    \int_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        {  1 } { January }
        {  2 } { Feburary }
        {  3 } { March }
        {  4 } { April }
        {  5 } { May }
        {  6 } { June }
        {  7 } { July }
        {  8 } { August }
        {  9 } { September }
        { 10 } { October }
        { 11 } { November }
        { 12 } { December }
      }
      { \int_eval:n {#1} }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\myset{10}
\begin{document}
\myget\\
\MonthName{\myget}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you for your explanation and working demo.